# How to ignore Icon? in git

Tags: macos, git

While trying to setup a dropbox folder with git, I saw a "Icon\r" file which is not created by me. I try to ignore it in the ~/.gitignore file. But adding `Icon\r` `Icon\r\r` `Icon?` won't work at all.

Comment: Actually `Icon?` works for me.

Comment: @johntex That means you'll be ignoring "Icon" + any following character.  So folders with names like "Icons" will get ignored as well, which is probably bad.

Comment: I have the same issue where I have a directory named **icons** as well as a sprite named **icons.svg**. My solution was to add `!icons` to my .gitignore file so directories and files will be allowed to use that name without getting ignored. Folder icons still get ignored as desired.

Comment: +1 for those who enlightened me that the **?** is **"\r"** or **"\r\r"**. Was having a hard time to find that out. My case was not for .gitignore but when listing a folder in PHP. I left both "Icon\r" and "Icon\r\r" in my exclude list, since the single \r was the one that worked for me. _I would use the printf solution for .gitignore._ Cheers!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

(This improves on the original answer, following a suggestion by **robotspacer**, according to **hidn**'s [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974028/192740).)

The `Icon?` is the file of OS X folder icon. The "`?`" is a special character for double carriage return (`\r\r`).

To tell `git` to ignore it, open a terminal and navigate to your repository folder.  Then type:

```
printf "Icon\r\r" >> .gitignore
```

If the file does not exist, it will be created and `Icon\r\r` will be its one line.  If the file does exist, the line `Icon\r\r` will be appended to it.

Comment: The `?` stands for a _single_ carriage return. As explained by hidn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974028/192740) the double `\r\r` works only due to git's interpretation of the last `\r` as part of the `\r\n` EOL convention and is indeed a worse choice than `[\r]`.

Comment: Combining the two suggestions, you can use this to add the safer version of the rule to an existing file: `printf "Icon[\r]" >> .gitignore`

Comment: I suggest adding more context around how many text editors (depending on their settings) may alter line endings. They do this with good intentions; e.g. in the spirit of standardizing line endings, but in this case, it makes editing a .gitignore file more difficult.

Comment: Due to practical considerations (we tend to use text editors, and these editors often 'correct' line endings), this approach is brittle. I suggested an alternative answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65429032/109618

Comment: The original answer that had been at the top of the post (with `>` instead of `>>`) clobbers the `.gitignore` file if it does exist.  Given that there's no reason to use it (`>>` works in both situations), I simply deleted it.  This protects users who hastily look for the first block of code in the accepted answer and copy it blindly. *raises hand sheepishly*

Answer (score 70):

You can use [vim](http://www.vim.org/) as well.

1. `vim .gitignore`
2. in a new line write `Icon`, then
3. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. repeat step 3
5. save and exit (shortcut: <kbd>ZZ</kbd>)

Now you should have `Icon^M^M` and it's done :)

For a smarter use you could add it to your gitignore global config file in `~/.gitignore_global`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need step 4? `$ find . -name "Icon^M^M"` gives nothing, but `$ find . -name "Icon^M"` gives `./Icon`. Is there something different about gitignore?

Comment: Actually, doesn't work on my system, neither with one `^M`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why we need *two* `^M` when it shows up in the `ls` results as just `Icon?` and a quick `git status` shows `"Icon\r"`? Weird.

Comment: Hi @LukeDavis! Probably the char `?` is multibyte?

Comment: You can (and should) specify the filename precisely with [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html); e.g. `find . -name $'Icon\r'`

Comment: This answer says what keys to press -- but not *what* these keypresses do -- or *why* they are necessary.

Answer (score 37):

"`Icon[\r]`" is probably a better alternative.
In vim, you just put `Icon[^M]`, which is `Icon[` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `]`.

The problem with "`Icon\r\r`" is EOL conversion.

The whole line is actually "`Icon\r\r\n`", counting line ending. Based on your setup, `CRLF` may be converted to `LF` on commit, so your repo will actually have "`Icon\r\n`". Say you sync the changes to another repo. You will get "`Icon\r\n`" in that working directory, which ignores `Icon` but not `Icon^M`. If you further edit `.gitignore` and commit it there, you will end up with "`Icon\n`" - completely losing `\r`.

I encountered this in a project where some develop on OS X while some on Windows. By using brackets to separate `\r` and the line ending, I don't have to repeat `\r` twice and I don't worry about EOL conversion.

Comment: Easiest solution on this discussion. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Wasn't able to get this to work unfortunately, but @rjatkinson's answer did work. (Not downvoting though as it may have just been me.)

Comment: For TextMate users: type `Icon[`, hit `⌃`+`⌥`+Enter, type `]`

Comment: Add following line to .gitattributes file to properly view the diff in terminal:

/.gitignore text diff

Answer (score 27):

**Regarding Naming (and Quoting) Things**: First, more people would benefit by knowing that [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) can be used to unambiguously match the macOS icon file. Both `Icon$'\r'` or `$'Icon\r'` and work in Bash and Zsh and most other modern shells, I hope, such as Fish.

**Keep Your .gitignore Editable**: While I'm impressed by the byte-level manipulation offered by other answers here, these methods are brittle in practice. Simply put, programmers tend to use text editors, and many of these editors are configured to alter line endings when saving a file. (For example, see this [VS Code discussion about line ending normalization](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127).)

Do you want your careful byte editing undone by your editor? Of course not. So perhaps you find it practical and convenient to configure your editor so that it doesn't affect line endings. You might look into (a) editor-specific configuration settings; or (b) cross-editor configuration (i.e. [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org)).

But this gets complex and messy. If want a **simpler, more flexible way**, use this in your .gitignore file:

```
# .gitignore
Icon?
![iI]con[_a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Explanation for the patterns:

- Use `Icon?` because the gitignore format does not support `\r` as an escape code.
- Use `[iI]` because Git can be case sensitive.
- Use `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` to catch many common ASCII characters; you may want to broaden this.

You can test that your gitignore patterns are working as expected with:

```sh
git check-ignore -v *
```

For example, for testing, with these files in a directory:

```
-rw-r--r--@  Icon?
-rw-r--r--   icon8
drwxr-xr-x   icons
-rw-r--r--   iconography
```

... the result of `git check-ignore -v *` is:

```
/Users/abc/.gitignore:3:Icon?   "Icon\r"
/Users/abc/.gitignore:4:![iI]con[_a-zA-Z0-9]    icon_
/Users/abc/.gitignore:4:![iI]con[_a-zA-Z0-9]    icons
```

This is what you want.

**Long Term Recommendation** This problem would be trivial to fix if Git supported the `\r` escape in .gitconfig files. One could simply write:

```
# .gitignore
Icon[\r]
```

So I suggest we engage with the [Git community](https://git-scm.com/community) and try to make this happen.

(If you do want to wade in and suggest a patch to Git, be sure to read  first.)

**References**

From the [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore/2.20.0):

> Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob: "*" matches anything except "/", "?" matches any one character except "/" and "[]" matches one character in a selected range. See fnmatch(3) and the FNM_PATHNAME flag for a more detailed description.

Please see [This linuxize.com article](https://linuxize.com/post/gitignore-ignoring-files-in-git/#square-brackets) for good examples of the square bracket syntax and negation syntax in .gitignore files.

For those that want to dig deep and see how pattern matching has changed over time in the Git source code, you can run this [search for uses of `fnmatch` in the git repository on GitHub](https://github.com/git/git/search?q=fnmatch).

Comment: This answer should be at the top, and the accepted answer should be changed to this. It is truly the best if you edit gitignore files both from the command line or using a text editor (or only the latter).

Comment: This one is more robust.

Answer (score 23):

The best place for this is in your global gitignore configuration file. You can create this file, access it, and then edit per the following steps:

`>> git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

`>> vim ~/.gitignore_global`

press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode

type `Icon` on a new line

while on the same line, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>

press <kbd>esc</kbd>, then <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> then type <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> then hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: This answer says what keys to press -- but not *what* they do -- or why they are necessary.

Comment: +1 Putting this in a global gitignore is the "one and only one truly obvious way to do it." `printf "Icon\r\r" >> ~/.gitignore_global` on the command line (as in eldes's answer) will add the line without using vim.

Answer (score 11):

The Icon? is the file of OSX folder icon. It turn out that `\r` is actually CRLF. So I use ruby to add the line to `.gitignore` file. Open terminal and navigate to `home` folder, then:

```
> irb
>> f = File.open(".gitignore", "a+") #<File:.gitignore>
>> f.write("Icon\r\r")  # output a integer
>> f.close
>> exit
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting just an update answer because the one above didn't work for me but actually simply adding `Icon?` in my `.gitignore` worked. If you look at your name file on your Finder, it is actually how it is displayed.

Comment: Note that `Icon?` will ignore things like "Icons" as well. For most of the answers to work your line ending should be `LF`, but on macs it's `CR`, AFAIK. And it also depends on your git's line ending conversion setting. It's displayed like that because many apps use "?" as a placeholder for any non-printable character.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked in TextMate: `Icon<CR><CR>`. The `<CR>` is a carriage return character, which is at `ctrl-alt-return` on the keyboard. You can also find it in the standard Character Viewer app searching for `cr`. Please note that the `<CR>` is an *invisible* character, so it's only visible if the editor is set up to show them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Icon[\r]` did not work for me. I had to use the following in `.gitignore`...

```
Icon*
```

I also added `Icon*` to my Settings > Core > Ignored Names in Atom...

```
.git, .hg, .svn, .DS_Store, ._*, Thumbs.db, desktop.inis, Icon*
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid wasting time on such trivial issues, I recommend using [gibo](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/gibo).

```
gibo dump macOS >> .gitignore
```

The result:

```
### Generated by gibo (https://github.com/simonwhitaker/gibo)
### https://raw.github.com/github/gitignore/e5323759e387ba347a9d50f8b0ddd16502eb71d4/Global/macOS.gitignore

# General
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon


# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `Icon?` to your .gitignore file and save it. It should do the job.

```html
Icon?
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).