# Git ignoring icon files because of Icon? rule

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a repo that includes SVG images in an `icons/` directory. Attempting to add these images to the repo fails, and Git complains with the error message:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
public/img/icons/my-icon.svg
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

When I traced the ignored files using [`git-check-ignore`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-check-ignore.txt), I found that the `Icon?` rule from my `.gitignore_global` file was the culprit.

```
$ git check-ignore -v public/img/icons/my-icon.svg 
/Users/ryanatallah/.gitignore_global:42:Icon?   public/img/icons/my-icon.svg
```

What might be an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the line `Icon?` from .gitignore_global or modify it to only match what you want to ignore?

Comment: Because I still want Git to ignore `Icon?` files.

Comment: When you say you want to ignore **icon** files, is there another pattern that would work instead of `Icon` ? For example - `*.ico`

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us which files you want ignored. Only files called Icon1, Icon2...? Everything that starts with Icon?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why that line is the culprit.  It should be matching `my-icon.svg` against `Icon?`... and it shouldn't match.  That seems odd to me.  Perhaps check-ignore is not functioning correctly.  Is there a `*.svg` rule in your `.gitignore_global`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out this problem is caused by a [Git bug](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/183) where the `Icon?` gitignore rule also matches directories such as `icons/`. The solution is to write the rule with the correct control character (which is a carriage return) at the end. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop) explains that `Icon?` files are automatically created for directories with custom icons.

The solution, as documented in [this blogpost](https://web.archive.org/web/20180310101714/http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/173740409/ignoring-icon-in-gitignore) is to correctly write the rule to my global gitignore file with the carriage return. The following Ruby script does the trick:

```
>> f = File.open(".gitignore", "a+") # append
=> #<File:.gitignore>
>> f.write("Icon\r\r")
=> 8
>> f.close
=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks for this! My colleague and I were pulling our hair out for half an hour on this one.

Comment: OS X: I tried adding another line to `.gitignore` after using this technique, but it got mixed with `Icon` on the same line. I bypassed the problem by deleting the `Icon` entry and adding it again, only using `f.write("Icon\r\r\n")` this time. After that, I was able to add another entry (`echo "file_to_ignore" >> .gitignore`).

Comment: `f.write("Icon[\r]\n")` seems preferable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974028/192740) for why. It also prevents Arnaud's problem.

Answer (score 5):

To override rules from the parent `.gitignore` file you need to use `!` prefix, for example  add in local `.gitignore` file:

```
!Icon
```