# Mystery git branch called 'Icon'

Tags: git, macos

I am working on OSX Yosemite. I seem to have a branch called `Icon`, which I certainly haven't created deliberately:

```
$ git branch
Icon
* master
```

But if I try to delete it does not find the branch:

```
$ git branch -D Icon
error: branch 'Icon' not found.
```

Similarly, I can't check it out:

```
$ git checkout Icon
error: pathspec 'Icon' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What on earth is going on?

Comment: What's the output of "git branch -a" and "git show-branch Icon"?

Comment: And take a look at .git/refs/* and .git/packed-refs

Comment: Also I'd try to clone the repo with `--mirror`

Answer (score 3):

It's not a branch.  The Icon? files are auto created by Google Drive sync client for OS X, and are a pain especially when you are using Git.  When you created the repo (or cloned it), OS X automatically put an Icon? file in every single directory, including your .git/branches directory:

```
$ ls .git/branches/
Icon?
```

See these related threads for more info: [How to ignore Icon? in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556250/how-to-ignore-icon-in-git)
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/6SIZ7nhNO4w

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your repo is in a good condition:

```
git fsck --full
```

This will verify the integrity of your repository.

---

#### `.git/refs/heads`

If once this command finish and you still don't see any problems (no error reported) check to see what branches are stored in your local `.git/refs/heads`.

Git store the branches information (SHA-1 in the branch names file) per branch. If you see a file named `Icon` there simply delete it.

---

#### `.git/packed-refs`

edit `.git/packed-refs`; if you see a line with your branch name (`Icon`) then delete it

[image]

---

#### Try to sync your local repo with the remote repo

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

This will download new branches data and will delete all the deleted remote info (branches, tags etc).

[image]

---

#### `git remote prune origin`

same as the above fetch with the `--prune` flag. Will remove any deleted data form the remote locally as well.

Comment: Thank you! When I run `git fsck --full` I see lots and lots of errors like this: `bad sha1 file: .git/objects/d9/Icon`. What would you advise?

Comment: Run this: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`