# git gc - fatal: bad object refs/remotes/Icon

Tags: git, version-control, garbage-collection, sourcetree

My `git gc` is giving me errors:

```
error: bad ref for Icon
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/Icon
error: failed to run repack
```

I know those `Icon` files are connected with OS X's auto-created files. 
I have added them to `.gitignore`.

But they could have been committed before I did this.

I am the only one who commits / has copy to the repository.

Thank you.

Comment: Theres a more detailed thread about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556250/how-to-ignore-icon-in-git)

Comment: @user3623413 while it is more detailed thread, it is about a slightly different topic. The problem described here is not about adding ?Icon into .gitignore  (which is actually straightforward). But the issue that arises when it was not added at the beginning and they were created inside ref. In which cases adding it into gitgnore (in any million ways) won't solve the fatal error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved it.

Apparently OS X just created those files in `ref` folder and `git` was looking for them.

So I have used a command to find and recursively delete all `Icon` files:

```
find . -name "Icon?" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Source: [Recursively Remove Icon? in Mac OSX.sh](https://gist.github.com/codystebbins/5507344)

Comment: Somehow I need to do this everytime I do `git pull` and on every repo in my mac. This can't be normal ways of working. Is there any permanent solution?