# How to add non printable characters to .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

On macOS, if you change a folder's icon, a file called "Icon\r" (carriage return) is created inside that directory. Now I don't know how to exclude it from git. Listing it as "Icon?" works, but that would also match "IconF" or anything like this.

Is there any escape sequence git understands in .gitignore files to match exaclty that character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question has been asked at [How to ignore Icon? in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556250/how-to-ignore-icon-in-git). And users have given the answers that amtch your specific requirement.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42369463/1281089

> For me this worked in TextMate: Icon

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974028/1281089

> "Icon[\r]" is probably a better alternative.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30755378/1281089

> printf "Icon\r\r" > .gitignore

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, you can't do this properly.

There is no encoding available, which is unfortunate since it's possible to have newlines in file names and `.gitignore` cannot express this.  Just as bad, if a line in `.gitignore` ends with a literal carriage return, the carriage return character is removed.  So you could ignore a file named `IconENTERX` by typing that into an editor that allows you to embed <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or <kbd>Return</kbd> depending on how your keys are labeled) characters (e.g., via <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> in vim), but not `IconENTER`.

You can get close enough, probably, for practical purposes by listing `Icon?` followed by `!Icon[A-Z]` or similar.