# VSCode on macOS - Hide Icon? file

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In macOS I have a file in a directory with the name `Icon?`, similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556250/how-to-ignore-icon-in-git).

I would like to add a pattern to exclude this file, however I'm not sure what pattern to use.

`**/Icon` and `**/Icon\r` don't work, and I don't want to use `**/Icon*` as it could potentially ignore other files, for example `Icon.png`

[image: VS Code Screenshot, showing Icon? file]

Answer (score 3):

Using the pattern `**/Icon?` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that sometimes `**/Icon?` is not enough, so I personally use:

```json
{
  "files.exclude": {
      "**/Icon?": true,
      "**/Icon\r": true,
  },
}
```